# Geotrellis, get the points that fall in a polygon grid Rdd

Tags: geotrellis

I need to calculate the average of the values of points that fall in a polygon grid.

Is like a join one to many based in condition Polyogon.contains(point)

```
//In:
val pointValueRdd : RDD[Feature[Point,Double]] 

val squareGridRdd : RDD[Feature[Polygon]]

//Needed Out:

val squareGridRdd : RDD[Feature[Polygon,(accum:Double,count:Int)]]
//or
val squareGridRdd : RDD[Feature[Polygon,average:Double]]
```

is possible to use some quadtree index ?

I read:clip to grid but i don not if it is the right tool.

http://geotrellis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/vectors.html#cliptogrid

The next image show the grid in blue, and the points

[image]

Some advice we welcome

Answer (score 4):

There is a straightforward way to accomplish this if your polygon grid can be expressed as a `LayoutDefinition` in GeoTrellis. A `LayoutDefinition` defines the grid of tiles that are used by GeoTrellis layers to represent large collection of raster tiles. It can also be used to perform transformations between a grid key (`SpatialKey`) in the grid space and bounding boxes (`Extent`s) of in the map space.

I won't assume that you can represent the grid by a LayoutDefinition and instead will show an example that solve the more general case. If you *can* represent your polygon grid by a LayoutDefinition, that approach will be more straightforward. However here is a code snippet of the more general approach. This was compiled but not tested, so if you find problems with it let me know. This is being included in our examples in the `doc-examples` project with this PR: https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/pull/2489

```scala
import geotrellis.raster._
import geotrellis.spark._
import geotrellis.spark.tiling._
import geotrellis.vector._

import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

import java.util.UUID

// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359243/geotrellis-get-the-points-that-fall-in-a-polygon-grid-rdd

val pointValueRdd : RDD[Feature[Point,Double]] = ???
val squareGridRdd : RDD[Polygon] = ???

// Since we'll be grouping by key and then joining, it's work defining a partitioner
// up front.
val partitioner = new HashPartitioner(100)

// First, we'll determine the bounds of the Polygon grid
// and the average height and width, to create a GridExtent
val (extent, totalHeight, totalWidth, totalCount) =
  squareGridRdd
    .map { poly =>
      val e = poly.envelope
      (e, e.height, e.width, 1)
    }
    .reduce { case ((extent1, height1, width1, count1), (extent2, height2, width2, count2)) =>
      (extent1.combine(extent2), height1 + height2, width1 + width2, count1 + count2)
    }

val gridExtent = GridExtent(extent, totalHeight / totalCount, totalWidth / totalCount)

// We then use this for to construct a LayoutDefinition, that represents "tiles"
// that are 1x1.
val layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition(gridExtent, tileCols = 1, tileRows = 1)

// Now that we have a layout, we can cut the polygons up per SpatialKey, as well as
// assign points to a SpatialKey, using ClipToGrid

// In order to keep track of which polygons go where, we'll assign a UUID to each
// polygon, so that they can be reconstructed. If we were dealing with PolygonFeatures,
// we could store the feature data as well. If those features already had IDs, we could
// also just use those IDs instead of UUIDs.
// We'll also store the original polygon, as they are not too big and it makes
// the reconstruction process (which might be prone to floating point errors) a little
// easier. For more complex polygons this might not be the most performant strategy.
// We then group by key to produce a set of polygons that intersect each key.
val cutPolygons: RDD[(SpatialKey, Iterable[Feature[Geometry, (Polygon, UUID)]])] =
  squareGridRdd
    .map { poly => Feature(poly, (poly, UUID.randomUUID)) }
    .clipToGrid(layoutDefinition)
    .groupByKey(partitioner)

// While we could also use clipToGrid for the points, we can
// simply use the mapTransform on the layout to determien what SpatialKey each
// point should be assigned to.
// We also group this by key to produce the set of points that intersect the key.
val pointsToKeys: RDD[(SpatialKey, Iterable[PointFeature[Double]])] =
  pointValueRdd
    .map { pointFeature =>
      (layoutDefinition.mapTransform.pointToKey(pointFeature.geom), pointFeature)
    }
    .groupByKey(partitioner)

// Now we can join those two RDDs and perform our point in polygon tests.
// Use a left outer join so that polygons with no points can be recorded.
// Once we have the point information, we key the RDD by the UUID and
// reduce the results.
val result: RDD[Feature[Polygon, Double]] =
  cutPolygons
    .leftOuterJoin(pointsToKeys)
    .flatMap { case (_, (polyFeatures, pointsOption)) =>
      pointsOption match {
        case Some(points) =>
          for(
            Feature(geom, (poly, uuid)) <- polyFeatures;
            Feature(point, value) <- points if geom.intersects(point)
          ) yield {
            (uuid, Feature(poly, (value, 1)))
          }
        case None =>
          for(Feature(geom, (poly, uuid)) <- polyFeatures) yield {
            (uuid, Feature(poly, (0.0, 0)))
          }
      }
    }
    .reduceByKey { case (Feature(poly1, (accum1, count1)), Feature(poly2, (accum2, count2))) =>
      Feature(poly1, (accum1 + accum2, count1 + count2))
    }
    .map { case (_, feature) =>
      // We no longer need the UUID; also compute the mean
      feature.mapData { case (acc, c) => acc / c }
    }
```